# How to create campaign through Apple Search Ads API

Tags: java, python-2.7, sh

I'm trying to  create  Campaign through Apple Search Ads API. So I use

```
curl -X POST https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v1/campaigns \
--cert path/XXXX.p12 \
--pass ****  \
-H "Authorization: orgId=xxxx" \
-d '{"budgetAmount":{"currency":"USD","amount": 50.0},"name": "weixinCampagin", "adamId":"414478124","adGroups": [{"name": "weixinCampaginAdGroup","startTime":"2017-03-17 00:00:00","defaultCpcBid": {"amount": 1,"currency":"USD"},"storeFronts": ["US"]}]}'
```

I got the following error messages:

```
{"data":null,"pagination":null,"error":{"errors":[{"messageCode":"INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE","message":"This is an invalid request. At least one field format is not readable by the system.","field":"Line#:1 Column#:50"}]}}
```

I have tried many times through different ways, but still not working. Is there any smart guys can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify that you're sending a json object.

```
curl \
 --cert ./<FILENAME>.p12 \
 --pass <PASSWORD> \
 -H "Authorization: orgId=<ORG_ID>" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d "<CAMPAIGN_DATA_FILE>.json" \
 -X POST "https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v1/campaigns"
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from content-type header, 
The amount needs to be in string format

```
'{"budgetAmount":{"currency":"USD","amount": "50.0"},"name": "weixinCampagin", "adamId":"414478124","adGroups": [{"name": "weixinCampaginAdGroup","startTime":"2017-03-17 00:00:00","defaultCpcBid": {"amount": "1","currency":"USD"},"storeFronts": ["US"]}]}'
```

in https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppStoreSearchAdsAPIReference/API_Overview.html
the sample also uses string for the amount item